# How do I programmatically add a ProgressBar in AsyncTask.onPreExecute?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

Code in async task:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(mScrollViewID);
        sv.removeAllViews();
        pb = new ProgressBar(mContext, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);
        pb.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        pb.setIndeterminate(true);
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
        tv.setText("Some text here.");
        sv.addView(pb);
    }
```

Note the `TextView` at the end - if I add that to the `ScrollView` instead, it shows up just fine. However, I can't seem to get the `ProgressBar` to display anything at all. It's my first time using the control - am I missing something silly?

Edit: if it matters, the `ScrollView` in use is defined in XML as:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollview0" android:layout_width = "match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true" android:padding="5dp">
```

Comment: Is it necessary that ProgressBar is instantiated  at RunTime?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `ProgressBar` width to `MATCH_PARENT` instead of `WRAP_CONTENT`?

Comment: @Chintan, more or less, yes (see below discussion) Squonk, yep, I've played around with a variety of values for the layout params, including explicit values (100, 100, for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem occurs many when you are creating ProgressBar dynamically

i suggest create one ProgressBar through xml

and set default **visibility GONE**

Comment: Show is not a method of ProgressBar, it's a method of ProgressDialog.

Comment: It has to be at least added and removed via code, because a `ScrollView` can only have a single child. I could perhaps load the layout from XML, but that really shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: you can add Any layour to scroll view and then you can add multiple component to that layout...

Comment: Understood, and I do that when adding the actual content. The problem is that sometimes I programmatically add `LinearLayout`, sometimes `RelativeLayout`, and sometimes just a `TextView`. It would be wasteful to have yet another layout for what is essentially just a very simple animation.  Also, in other cases, I will want this control for a sort of 'Image Gallery' - so I will load ~30 images via AsyncTasks, will need a ProgressBar for each, in which case it's impossible to have them pre-placed in the XML layout. Note - I tried inserting a `LinearLayout` between the controls, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

if you add `tv` after `pb` it deffinatyl shows the error?

It is because a `ScrollView` only host one child. So what you need to add a `LinearLayout` in your `ScrollView` and then add other stuff in your `Linear layout`

Comment: I don't think you understood the question...the tv is only there to demonstrate that adding a child to the `ScrollView` IS visible, unlike the `ProgressBar`. The tv is only there for debugging purposes, and will be going away.

Comment: hmmm....other then your code looks perfect to me.`ScrollView` is your parent View? If it is not the parent then try to give the height of your `ScrollView`. Say `100dip`